# Text mining with R: use of sub

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, term-document-matrix

I am on a project with R and I am starting to get my hands dirty with it.

In the first part I try to clean the data of vector msg. But later when I build the `termdocumentmatrix`, these characters still appear.
I would like to remove words with less than 4 letters and remove punctuation

```
gsub("\\b\\w{1,4}\\b ", " ", pclbyshares$msg)
gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", pclbyshares$msg) 
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(pclbyshares$msg))
TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq=120, highfreq=Inf)
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Have a look at `?tm_map` and `?content_transformer`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stored your first two lines of code as variables to use later. So, in your third line, where you create your `corpus` variable, you are using the unmodified `msg` data. Give this a try:

```
msg_clean <- gsub("\\b\\w{1,4}\\b ", " ", pclbyshares$msg)
msg_clean <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", msg_clean) 
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(msg_clean))
TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
findFreqTerms(tdm, lowfreq = 120, highfreq = Inf)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to remove the punctuation yet

Comment: Does `msg_clean` look as intended after the first two lines above are run?